# Flutter - Two stateful in one stateless or two stateless in one stateful

Tags: flutter, architecture, stateless, stateful, state-management

I'm quite new to Flutter and I struggle to understand at which stage I should use Stateful widgets. To illustrate my issue, here is a simple layout.

[Simple Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xaSm.png)

Let assume that we want to change the background color of the containers when they are tapped by the user.

Should I make my HomePage widget a Stateful widgets holding the state of the containers ? Or should I make my HomePage a Stateless widget and make my two containers stateful widgets holding their state ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand when you need to use Stateful Widget. Flutter offical website says that

> Stateful widgets are useful when the part of the user interface you are describing can change dynamically, e.g. due to having an internal clock-driven state, or depending on some system state.

You probably want to change the state of one Container at a time when tapped, not the the whole HomePage. Therefore, if you make HomePage Stateful Widget, you will have to re-render both Containers when one of them tapped. If you make both Containers Stateful Widget separately and HomePage Stateless Widget, only the Container which is tapped will be rebuilt. So, the benefits of choosing one over another change depending on your goal. Choose the one works better for you.